# Run light gallery with a href or button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightgallery

Hello stackoverflow community. I am using lightGallery plug-in and have a problems with making it running with external kind of button in my case anchor tag, can you suggest what have i done wrong or maybe any other way to get it working right.

**HTML**

```
<a href="fullscreen">Enter full screen view</a>

<div class="owl-carousel" id="selector1">
    <div class="item" data-src="img/1.jpg" name="fullscreen"><img src="img/1.jpg">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lightgallery").lightGallery(); 
});

$('#selector1').lightGallery({
    selector: '.item'
});
```

lightGallery plug-in: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/#installation

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things that might/will cause problems:

- The `href` attribute does not work like that. The link will just open another website. Instead you need to execute some javascript to activate the fullscreen mode, when the link is clicked.
- You have two opening `<div>` tags, but only one closing. Also, you should close the `<img>` tag.
- You probably want all of your posted javascript in the `$(document).ready(function() {});` function
- There is no element with the id `lightgallery`.
- I don't know anything about the `data-src` attribute.

This should fix most of the problems, however it will not enable the fullscreen functionality:

**html**

```
<div class="owl-carousel" id="lightgallery">
    <div class="item" data-src="img/1.jpg">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lightgallery').lightGallery({
        selector: '.item'
    });
});
```